# Eigenvalues of a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Given a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix

\begin{equation} 
M= \begin{pmatrix}
A & B & C \\
B & D & E \\ 
C & E & F\\ 
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}

how do I find the eigenvalues? Brute-forcing it by looking at the roots of the characteristic polynomial seems overwhelming.

Are there any properties of symmetric matrices that might simplify the problem or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Lordofdark very relevant, but it doesn't provide a definitive answer to the question.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I read it before I posted, but like @Omnomnomnom stated, they do not provide a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is (to my knowledge) no pencil and paper method for computing **exact** eigenvalues that exploits the symmetry of a matrix.

It is notable, however, that the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix will necessarily be real. So, at the very least, that's a fact you can use to check for mistakes.

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=355578.366316

Comment: @Museful Interesting find.  I can't access the article; the abstract says "an explicit solution was developed. The resulting expressions are remarkably simple and neat, hence this note" but I wonder whether those formulas would make for a viable pen and paper approach

Comment: What do you think of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#3%C3%973_matrices

Comment: @Museful Useful perhaps, but it doesn't use the fact that $A$ is symmetric

Comment: The algorithm reads only the matrix entries in the upper triangle.

Comment: @Museful ah, and that's exactly the algorithm from the paper you linked. Yes, I suppose that is a viable pencil and paper approach.  Feel free to write up an answer to this question about it.

Answer (score 1):

In the general$^*$ case there is no escape, you *must* solve a cubic equation. (I am not talking about particular cases such that the coefficients and roots are rational or solutions can be spotted by inspection.)

Because whatever method you will use will deliver those roots, and will constitute an equivalent of Cardano's formulas. In addition, as the three roots are real, you can be in the *casus irreductibilis* an need trigonometric functions.

---

$^*$Note that the matrix has $6$ independent coefficients. This is more than enough to correspond to a general cubic polynomial.